# Extracting images of digits from a dataset in digits classification in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

Im trying to implement digit classification with knn alogorithm.

```
#pseudocode
    note:(the order of the digits follow the order of the labels)
    i.e 
    train={digit0,digit0,digit1,digit2...}

    label={0,0,1,2...}
    labels.shape = (10000,)
    train.shape=(784*1000)
```

i have a huge dataset of 10000 digits from 0 to 9 as images of 28 * 28 pixels along with their labels.the labels and digits are arranged in same order.
SO i need to extract the digits 0 and 1 from the dataset and perform knn for different values of k={1,2,3,4,5} for digits 0 and 1 which are 28*28 pixels.i need help with digits extraction.

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: what is `label` and `train` - list, array or DataFrame (pandas) ? For DataFrame You could use something like `train[ (label == 0) | (label == 1) ]`. For `list` you would have to use `for`-loop and use indexes `range(len(label))`. Eventually `zip(label, train)`

Comment: actually i have zipped both the digits and labels. but how do i extract specific digit 0 and 1 from the zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `numpy` `array` you can use

```
selected = train[ (label == 0) | (label == 1) ]
```

---

```
import numpy as np

train = np.array(['digit0-1', 'digit0-2', 'digit1-1', 'digit2-1'])
label = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2])

selected = train[ (label == 0) | (label == 1) ]

print(selected)
```

---

For `pandas` `DataFrame` something similar

```
selected = train['item'][ (label['val'] == 0) | (label['val'] == 1) ]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['digit0-1', 'digit0-2', 'digit1-1', 'digit2-1']})
label = pd.DataFrame({'val': [0, 0, 1, 2]})

selected = train['item'][ (label['val'] == 0) | (label['val'] == 1) ]

print(selected)
```

or if you will keep all in one `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'train': ['digit0-1', 'digit0-2', 'digit1-1', 'digit2-1'],
    'label': [0, 0, 1, 2]
})

selected = df['train'][ (df['label'] == 0) | (df['label'] == 1) ]

print(selected)
```

---

For normal `list` you could use `zip()` to create pairs

```
train = ['digit0-1', 'digit0-2', 'digit1-1', 'digit2-1']
label = [0, 0, 1, 2]

selected = []

for t, l in zip(train, label):
    if l in (0, 1):
        selected.append(t)

print(selected)
```

The same with list comprehension

```
train = ['digit0-1', 'digit0-2', 'digit1-1', 'digit2-1']
label = [0, 0, 1, 2]

selected = [t for t, l in zip(train, label) if l in (0, 1)]

print(selected)
```